# how to fill the datagridview2 with information from datagridivew1 c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

please help me, how to fill the datagridview2 with information from datagridivew1. Example, i fill column 1 (dgv2) with barcode it stored on datagridview1, and after it filled, i want column 2 (dgv2) to fill with the product name (from dgv1).. please help me

Comment: Your question is not clear.Please explain it clearly.

Comment: hmm... when i input idproduct from dgv1 in dgv2, dgv2 can show automatically the product name (product name stored in dgv1)

Answer (score 0):

You will to have to use CellContent and CelValueChanged event to get this functionality.